# How to pre-compute value lookup in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out the right syntax for "pre-computing" the property value to look up in the "withPrefix" function below so that I can pass that function around and it will not depend on the current value of x at the time of execution.

```
var a = { 
    one: 'First Name',
    two: 'Last Name'
};

var x = 'one';
var withPrefix = function(value) {
    return a[x] + ": " + value;
};

console.log(withPrefix);
```

Of course this is a contrived example and the real one is more complex, but tried to reduce it to simplest case. The console.log output says:

```
function (value) {
    return a[x] + ": " + value;
}
```

But I want it to be something like:

```
function (value) {
    return a['one'] + ": " + value;
}
```

I use jQuery and RequireJS. If either of those libraries have any helpers for this, that would be an acceptable solution, but I suspect there's a pure javascript way of doing it.

Comment: Any problem with passing `x` as a parameter? Else, you can use a function factory/closure for what you want if I understood correctly.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté would prefer not to pass x as parameter. The reasons relate to the larger (non-contrived) code and would be hard to explain here

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is your exact goal, are you trying to optimize things only or do you just want to have the same value for `x` inside of the function independently of the outer scope's `x`?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté the latter: Use the value for x at the time I build this function, but then not use it later when the function is called.

Comment: Use `eval()`, it's great and not evil at all.

Comment: You can probably use bfavaretto's answer or this [factory version](http://jsfiddle.net/rpCUj/2) which does the same thing but also supports older browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you want is a closure? Use a factory function (function that generates functions) for this:

```
function make_withPrefix (x) {
    return function (value) {
        return a[x] + ": " + value;
    }
}
```

So now you can generate the appropriate withPrefix function:

```
var withPrefix_one = make_withPrefix('one');
var withPrefix_two = make_withPrefix('two');

withPrefix_one('Han');   // returns "First Name : Han"
withPrefix_two('Solo');  // returns "Second Name : Solo"
```

Just plain old javascript. No fancy new features like bind or anything and no horrible quoting hell in strings. Supported since Netscape Navigator and IE1

Answer (score 1):

You could have some fun with partial function application and [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
function masterFunc(x, value) {
    return a[x] + ": " + value;
}
var xValFunc = masterFunc.bind(null, 'one');
console.log(xValFunc('foo')); // First Name: foo
```

Comment: Didn't think of using `bind` to bind the first argument, nice solution.

Comment: Embedded the link in the answer, thanks. I also didn't think of it until I recently answered something similar (using call or apply), and someone suggested bind. It's shorter, and one can always use a shim on older browsers where it's not supported.

Comment: Yes, the MDN link is specially useful when it contains a shim such as this one. `=]`

Answer (score 0):

if i understand it right. you wanner make a local scope try somthing like this:

```
var withPrefix = (function(){
  //create a new scope
        /* all viables created here cant be seen by the souronding code */
  var x = "one"
    , a = 
      { one: "First Name"
      , two: "Last Name"
      }
  return function(value){
    // the withPrefix function
    return a[x] + ": " + value //make the string using the Local object a
  }
}())
withPrefix("foo") // returns: "First Name: foo"
console.log(a) // returns undefined
console.log(x) // returns undefined
```